# SKShapeNode fillColor adding 3 more draw calls

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I am making a game in SpriteKit. I am creating a `SKShapeNode` and adding it to a `SKSpriteNode` (stone) already in the scene.

```
shapeNode               = SKShapeNode(path: self.oldPath)
shapeNode.fillColor     = wave.color
shapeNode.strokeColor   = .clear
shapeNode.position      = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -5)  // Offset for wave paths
stone.addChild(shapeNode)
```

[image]

Here is what is strange, the total scene's draws:

[image: Total draws]
<sup>When I say "not set", I mean that I commented out that line.</sup>

It appears that setting `fillColor` increases the draws by `3`, and setting `strokeColor` decreases the draws by `1`, although doing this does not produce the desired shape node.

What is causing the increase in draw calls, and how can I prevent/reduce this?

---

*Edit 1:*

The problem is that this is an animating wave around a stone (as if there is a stone in water, see image above). It would not increase performance by rasterising it and make it as a sprite texture, as the wave is constantly animating. This would most likely decrease performance.

I also don't want to use an Atlas to quickly change a texture, as I want this wave to look random, smooth, and natural.

Comment: define what "strokeColor not set" means.... if you mean .clear, then that is not "not set' and involves alpha blending, even if it is clear

Comment: When I said “not set”, I mean that I just commented out the line so no values were set by me.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon What can I do to fix this or reduce the draw calls?

Comment: Dont use skshapenode.   Render it once, and turn it into a texture for skspritenode

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I added a bit more detail, but ask any questions if it is still not clear or you want me to be more specific about something.

Comment: You may want to look into SKEffectNode

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks! I will have a look into that  How would I arrange where to put the effect node in my case? I have a stone sprite - which then has 2 children: the near wave, and the far wave (seen as different colours in the image from the question). Would the animating waves be a child of the effect node which is added to the stone sprite, or should the effect node hold the stone sprite *and* the waves? What about if I want to render many different stones and waves on the scene?

Comment: Whatever is animating and rippling gets placed in the effect node,  so it would be Stone -> EffectNode -> Nodes/images to have an effect.  I am not sure which may be better to be honest.  You could also try setting your `.blendMode` to `.replace` in your SKShapeNode,  that may reduce drawcounts, but you also lose transparency.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I have been playing around with SKEffectNode, but I'm now getting 9 draws, even if I try rasterise which I shouldn't as it is not static. My animation on the SKShapeNode/wave is just an animating path, changing every frame.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is create a hollow SKShapeNode so that your SKShapeNode has the ripple path,  then use a Shader or an SKSpriteNode to fill in the shape.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon So create a shape node with `.clear` stroke, and then fill in using a shader or texture? I don't know how to use shaders, and don't want to spend a while doing that, so how do I achieve this with a sprite node?

Comment: not a clear stroke,  whatever color you need your ripple to be

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Right ok. But how do I fill this in with a sprite node?

Comment: You create a white sprite the size and shape of your stone.  You then use `scale`, `color`. and `colorBlendFactor` to get it to the color you need.  This handles fill.  Then the SKShapeNode ring gets placed on top of this

Comment: It should reduce the draw count to 3 if I am figuring this correctly.  1 for the sprite and 2 for the stroke.  If you do replace blendMode, it may drop it down to 2 draw calls

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I don't see how this would allow the shape node (the wave) to appear filled in correctly, as it is an irregular shape and NOT the shape of the stone. The wave path is calculated using a random variation along the hexagon shape.

Comment: Your stroke should be think enough to disguise the solid shape underneath it.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'll get back to you in ~10 minutes to let you know if this works :)

Comment: If you want to get a little more fancy,  you render your SKShapeNode as a donut so that you can have a different inner stroke and outer stroke

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Can't finish it right now, but I'll get back.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Late reply, but I've been busy!  I have managed to half the draw calls to `4` now which is a brilliant improvement, and as good as I think it will go for what I have. Your comment about making a thick stroke really helped! I scrapped the idea of the shape to fill it in like you mentioned through, as I just made the stroke a little closer to the edge of the stone because this saved an extra draw call and still looks similar to what I had originally. Thanks!  (small bonus benefit - the waves haven't got such harsh edges due to the thick stroke with `lineJoin = .round`).